# SQL - read from XML variables

Tags: sql, xml, variables

how can I select values from this XML type on the SQL server 2022 ?

```
<Variables>
  <Variable Name="Menge [Stk]" Variable="N" Value="1" ClientDoc="0" CDchangeable="0" ValueChangeAble="1" OnProdPaper="0" ExChangeEuro="0" AVSVariable="0" />
</Variables>
```

Individual variables will be a column.

Thanks.

I tried this, but no values of variables are shown :

```
select 'Name1' [Name]
, '<Variables><Variable Name="Menge [Stk]" Variable="N" Value="1" ClientDoc="0" CDchangeable="0" ValueChangeAble="0" OnProdPaper="0" ExChangeEuro="0" AVSVariable="0"/></Variables>  ' [VariablesXML]
into #TempTable
;
select [Name], VariablesXML, CAST(VariablesXML as XML) [VariablesXML] from #TempTable
;
with P as (select [Name], CAST(VariablesXML as XML) [VariablesXML] from #TempTable)
select T.[Name]
, LX.VariablesXML
, X.N.value('Name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [Name]
, X.N.value('Variable[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [Variable]
, X.N.value('Value[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [Value]
from #TempTable T
inner join P LX on T.Name = LX.Name
outer apply LX.VariablesXML.nodes('/Variables') as X(N)
;
drop table #TempTable
;
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts you are trying to retrieve are attributes, so you use @ syntax:

```
, X.N.value('Variable[1]/@Name', 'nvarchar(max)') [Name]
```

i.e. the Name attribute of the first Variable element.

Comment: Perfect, I do the first time the XML export of values.
Thanks a lot!